# R : Setting Red and Green Values of an RGB image to Zero by handling it as a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, grayscale

I am working with the OpenImageR and SuperpixelImageSegmentation packages in R.
i wanted to extract the Green dimension of a segmented image, the result is a two dimensional image instead of 3 (grayscale).
so to colorize it i set the Red and Blue Values of the colored image to 0.
However, whenever i try to show the image i get the following error, and i can't understand why 0 is intrepreted to be NAN, i also tried setting it to a value that is superior to zero (0.01), and i still get the same message :

```
Error in rgb(t(x[, , 1L]), t(x[, , 2L]), t(x[, , 3L]), maxColorValue = max) : 
  color intensity nan, not in [0,1]
```

here is my code :

```
library(SuperpixelImageSegmentation)
library(OpenImageR)

path = system.file("tmp_images", "Phen.jpg", package = "OpenImageR")

image = readImage(path)
init = Image_Segmentation$new()

segmentation = init$spixel_segmentation(input_image = image,
                                    superpixel = 2000, # k
                                    AP_data = TRUE,
                                    use_median = TRUE,
                                    sim_wA = 5,
                                    sim_wB = 5,
                                    sim_color_radius = 3,
                                    kmeans_method = "kmeans",
                                    kmeans_initializer = "kmeans++",
                                    kmeans_num_init = 5,
                                    kmeans_max_iters = 50,
                                    verbose = TRUE)
#getting the green part alone
imG = segmentation$AP_image_data
imG = imG[,,2]

imB = segmentation$AP_image_data
imB = imB[,,3]

imR = segmentation$AP_image_data
imR = imR[,,1]


imR4 = imR / 2
imB4 = imB / 2
imGDone = imG - imR4
imGDone = imGDone - imB4
imageShow(imGDone)  # works fine, the result is a mask that contains only the green concentrated areas

imGColor <- segmentation$AP_image_data
for (i in 1:nrow(imGDone)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(imGDone)){
    if (imGColor[i,j,1] > 0) {
      imGColor[i,j,1] = 0 * imGDone[i,j] # setting red to zero
      imGColor[i,j,3] = 0 * imGDone[i,j] # setting blue to zero
      imGColor[i,j,2] = 1 * imGDone[i,j] # setting green
    }
  }
}

imageShow(imGColor)
```

when i execute the last line to display imGColor i get the error.
i'm new to R, and i can't find any leads on what might be the cause of it.
and so i would like help on what i should do, and thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a 'SuperpixelImageSegmentation' or 'OpenImageR' issue. The 'imageShow' function of the 'OpenImageR' package uses under the hood the [grid::grid.raster](https://github.com/mlampros/OpenImageR/blob/master/R/shiny_rscript.R#L32) function. The error that you receive is due to the fact that the modified values of R,G,B are not in the range between 0 and 1 as mentioned also in another [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110824/8302386). To overcome this issue you have to first normalize the pixel values to [0,1] and then make your adjustments. The 'path' to the file that you've mentioned does not exist in the 'OpenImageR' package therefore I used another available image of the package,

```
    library(SuperpixelImageSegmentation)
    library(OpenImageR)

    path = system.file("tmp_images", "2.jpg", package = "OpenImageR")

    image = readImage(path)
    init = Image_Segmentation$new()

    segmentation = init$spixel_segmentation(input_image = image,
                                            superpixel = 2000, # k
                                            AP_data = TRUE,
                                            use_median = TRUE,
                                            sim_wA = 5,
                                            sim_wB = 5,
                                            sim_color_radius = 3,
                                            kmeans_method = "kmeans",
                                            kmeans_initializer = "kmeans++",
                                            kmeans_num_init = 5,
                                            kmeans_max_iters = 50,
                                            verbose = TRUE)
    #getting the green part alone
    imG = segmentation$AP_image_data
    imG = imG[,,2]

    imB = segmentation$AP_image_data
    imB = imB[,,3]

    imR = segmentation$AP_image_data
    imR = imR[,,1]


    imR4 = imR / 2
    imB4 = imB / 2
    imGDone = imG - imR4
    imGDone = imGDone - imB4
    imageShow(imGDone)  # works fine, the result is a mask that contains only the green concentrated areas

    # the 'imGDone' array has values in the range [-0.08039, -0.03824] 
    summary(as.vector(imGDone))

    # you have to normalize first to [0,1] to avoid the error
    imGDone <- OpenImageR::NormalizeObject(imGDone)

    # values now in the range [0.0000, 1.0000]
    summary(as.vector(imGDone))

    imGColor <- segmentation$AP_image_data

    for (i in 1:nrow(imGDone)) {
      for (j in 1:ncol(imGDone)){
        if (imGColor[i,j,1] > 0) {
          imGColor[i,j,1] = 0 * imGDone[i,j] # setting red to zero
          imGColor[i,j,3] = 0 * imGDone[i,j] # setting blue to zero
          imGColor[i,j,2] = 1 * imGDone[i,j] # setting green
        }
      }
    }

    imageShow(imGColor)
```